# add a temporary column in SQL, where the values depend from another column

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have this table:

```
ID | name | result | 
--------------------    
 1 |  A   |   1    |
--------------------
 2 |  B   |   2    |
--------------------
 3 |  C   |   1    |
--------------------
 1 |  A   |   2    |
--------------------
 4 |  E   |   2    |
--------------------
```

I want to add a new temporary column next to |result|, and where result=1 the value should be 100, and where result=2 the value should be 80 so it should look like this:

```
ID | name | result | NewColumn|
-------------------------------    
 1 |  A   |   1    |  100     |
-------------------------------
 2 |  B   |   2    |   80     |
-------------------------------
 3 |  C   |   1    |  100     |
-------------------------------
 1 |  A   |   2    |  80      |
-------------------------------
 4 |  E   |   2    |  80      |
-------------------------------
```

How can I query this in SQL ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use a [`CASE` expression](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) in your `SELECT`'s column list - something like this:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    name,
    result,
    CASE
        WHEN result = 1 THEN 100
        WHEN result = 2 THEN 80
        ELSE NULL
    END AS NewColumn
FROM YourTable
```

Add additional `WHEN` expressions or alter the `ELSE` expression as needed.

Comment: How do you save that column in the database?

Comment: Related questions should be asked separately, but look into SQL's `INSERT INTO SELECT` statement.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `case` statement to your query:

```
SELECT id, name, result, CASE result WHEN 1 THEN 100 WHEN 2 THEN 80 ELSE NULL END
from   my_table
```

Comment: What if there are other values besides 1 and 2 in result?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ID
,name
,result
,NewColumn = CASE WHEN result = 1 THEN 100 WHEN result = 2 THEN 80 END 
FROM Table1
```

Answer (score 1):

As the answers given above are also correct. But I will say that if you have a predefined relation or logic between the existing column and the new column then you can also achieve that without the `CASE`. Writing `CASE` for all the possible values would not be possible nor efficient.

For your existing data. I can use it something like this

```
SELECT ID, name, result, (20*(6-result)) as NewColumn
FROM YourTable
```

Here I am assuming that `1=>100`, `2=>80`, `3=>60`, `4=>40`, `5=>20`.

of course this only for understanding purpose. You can create your own expression depending on the actual data.

Comment: now can we use NewColumn2 = NewColumn * 100 as NewColumn2?

Answer (score 1):

You would use IF Statement in Mysql

SELECT col1,col2,col3, IF(col3=1,'100', IF(col3=2,80,''))
FROM your_table