# How can I "where" raw column(DB::raw). [LARAVEL]

Tags: laravel

**My Objective** for these, is to make an autocomplete input text for location. When I type something like 'streetNo', 'city' or 'country' relevant data should return
I just created a raw column "full_address" joining "streetNo", "city", & "country" column.

**Heres my code:**

```
$searchAddress = $r->input('address'); //dynamic

$profile = DB::table('student')
    ->select(
        'students.id',
        'students.name',
        'students.class',
        'students.schedule',
        'inf.streetNo',
        'inf.city',
        'inf.country',
        DB::raw("(CONCAT(inf.streetNo,' ',inf.city,' ',inf.country)) AS full_address")
    )
    ->where('full_address', 'LIKE', "%{$searchAddress}%")
    ->join('informations AS inf', 'inf.student_id', 'students.id')
    ->get();
```

**I tried** to search existing data like "city or country" but no data returned. I suspect there something wrong of "where-ing" the data. 

**Question is** can we "where" temporary column like "full_address column" like the code shown above?? Because I tried that code and no data returned when there is actually

Need your help, Sirs..

Comment: You have to combine `CASE`. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21885551/add-a-temporary-column-in-sql-where-the-values-depend-from-another-column/21885692) answer to get an idea.

Comment: When you say not working does the query fail or are you not getting data you're expecting and if it's the 2nd case can you share some data you'd expect to get but are not getting along with a query?

Comment: @apokryfos already edited my question Sir. Could you mine to read it again, thanks Sir.

Comment: @Tpojka thanks for reply Sir. Sir I'm not using "CASE WHEN", I'm just using "CONCAT".

Comment: I understand. I am just giving you idea what has to be considered. Check here [also](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/91173/select-where-case). In your situation it'd be something like `SELECT your_fields_here WHERE (CASE WHEN full_address LIKE '%$searchAddress%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` or something similar to this. You should investigate but I think this is the way.

Comment: @Tpojka sorry Sir I don't get it. The "full_address" column is actually working Sir and there is data returned. My only problem is that I can't search or "where" the "full_address" column.

Comment: @Tpojka this line I really suspects, there is something wrong. `->where('full_address', 'LIKE', "%{$searchAddress}%")`

Comment: I am telling you how I would approach to that problem. Again, check two links I found on site for you and study it for a bit. You can't search something that doesn't exist. And temporary column doesn't exist. You should make/return one to have it for checking against comparing part. But what you can is to return only rows that comply to that case as I proposed you to do. You should try it with raw query first and after you have working query, only then try to convert to eloquent query builder. 
`->where('full_address', 'LIKE', "%{$searchAddress}%")` won't work but try with raw query first.

Comment: @Tpojka ahh okey2 Sir.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17092112/laravel-eloquent-select-case) you have something similar to that (raw query).

Comment: Example data please. Try making a db fiddle that reproduces this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Got the solution!!

I try different ways on how to **"where"** the **raw column** but no data returned, so I assume that these code
`->where('full_address', 'LIKE', "%{$searchAddress}%")` 
is I think syntax error.

**We can't use "where clause" to raw columns** such like "full_address".

**So what I did** is, I did not make a raw column such as "full_address" anymore, instead I directly "where" the DB::Raw

See my final and working codes:

```
$searchAddress = $r->input('address'); //dynamic

$profile = DB::table('student')
    ->select(
        'students.id',
        'students.name',
        'students.class',
        'students.schedule',
        'inf.streetNo',
        'inf.city',
        'inf.country'
    )
    ->where(DB::raw("CONCAT(inf.streetNo,' ',inf.city,' ',inf.country)), 'LIKE', "%{$searchAddress}%")
    ->join('informations AS inf', 'inf.student_id', 'students.id')
    ->get();
```